# Configure Gmail API on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: python, api, ubuntu, gmail, vps

How to configure Gmail API on a AWS Ubuntu VPS? I am able to make it work properly on my Linux Machine, but after I run the code on my VPS, it asks me to authenticate by visiting the URL. I copied the URL and tried authenticating myself. While authenticating myself in browser, I am redirected to `localhost:<random-port>?state=...` and cannot authenticate myself as it cannot connect to localhost. How can I configure this properly on my Ubuntu VPS?

i have used the default code provided by google developers: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem.
When you will try to authenticate using your browser, it will try to redirect you to some localhost URL. Just copy that localhost URL, log in to your VPS, open the terminal, type python3 (or python), and finally type these commands:

```
import requests
url = "http://localhost:xxxxx-url-you-got-in-your-browswer"
resp = requests.get(url)
exit()
```

After these commands, it should generate a Gmail API token.